# Showing that a set of trigonometric functions is a basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra

Once again I am asking for help, I'm preparing for my linear algebra exam by doing a practice exam. The problem goes as following.

Let $\beta$ be the subset $\{1,e^x\cos x,e^x\sin x\}$ of a vector space of infinite many differentiable real functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $V=\text{Span} \beta$ then $\beta$ is a basis for $V$. Now let $\mathcal{C}=\{1+e^x\cos x,1+e^x\sin x,e^x\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)\}$ I have to show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a basis for $V$. For it to be a basis of $V$ it has to span $V$ and be linearly independent. To show that $\mathcal{C}$ is linearly indepdent, let $a,b,c,d,e,f\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\mapsto a+be^x\cos x+c+de^x\sin x+e^x\left(e\cos x + f\sin x \right)$ is the $\theta(x)$ function, i.e the zero function. Meaning that we have to show $a=b=c=d=e=f=0$. Do I just test with different values, i.e letting $x=0,\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}...$. I'm not sure if this helps, but I noticed that if we denote the functions in $\beta$ as $\beta=\{f_1,f_2,f_3\}$ then $\mathcal{C}=\{g_1,g_2,g_3\}$ in other words $g_1=f_1+f_2, g_2=f_1+f_3, g_3=f_3+f_2$. I also tried differentiating it, I noticed that then $a=c=0$

Answer (score 1):

$a(1+e^x\cos x)+b(1+e^x\sin x)+c(e^x\left(\cos x+\sin x\right))=0$

$(a+b)+(a+c)e^x\cos x+(b+c)e^x\sin x=0$

we know that elements of $\{1,e^x\cos x,e^x\sin x\}$ are lienarly independent so

$c_1+c_2e^x\cos x+c_3e^x\sin x=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$ Hence

$a+b=a+c=b+c=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $a=b=c=0$ which means they are linearly independent

so C forms a basis